# Sqlite insert statement doesn't add records in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to execute a simple hard-coded insert statement for a SqLite database. The code works and I get a success message from my own NSLog, however, no records are added to the database. Can anyone help?  THx! Viv

```
-(void)addFavorites{
    const char *sqlInsert = "insert into rivers (stat_ID, stat_Name, state) values ('03186500','WILLIAMS RIVER','WA')";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sqlInsert, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
        NSLog(@"RECORD ADDED!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"RECORD NOT ADDED!");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: Have you copied your database out of the bundle?

Comment: The usual reason for this symptom is that the user is trying to operate on the copy of the DB in the bundle.  The bundle is read-only, and the DB must be copied from there to read/write space to be modified.

Comment: You *must* check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

Comment: So if the bundle is read only, what is the best way to use sqlite to persist data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have code like this in your app delegate to copy the database out of the bundle to your NSDocuments directory? Be sure to copy the database to there, then point to there  when you're running your sqlite3_open, not to the bundle. The NSDocument directory will be saved when the device is synced to iTunes or iCloud, so it's the place you want your database to be for maintaining data.

```
NSString *databaseName = @"MyDatabase.sqlite";  
NSArray *systemPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = [systemPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databaseFullPath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@",@"/",databaseName];

//copy the database to the file system if it hasn't been done yet.
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL exists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databaseFullPath];
if(exists == NO)
{
    NSString *dbPathInBundle = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPathInBundle toPath:databaseFullPath error:nil];
}
```